# Config emacs + erlang for wxErlang usage

Tags: erlang, wxerlang

Hello
Erlang requires -smp for using wxErlang. As I edit and compile with emacs, I modified the erlang.el file like this:
(defvar inferior-erlang-machine-options '("-smp")

But this has no effect when I run the program:
WX ERROR: SMP emulator required** exception error: not_smp

Do you see a syntax error or anything else ?

Comment: (defvar inferior-erlang-machine-options '("-smp")) hangs emacs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-smp` option requires an argument (`enable`, `disable` or `auto`). If you always want to start an SMP-enabled emulator, add the following to your `~/.emacs` file:

```
 (add-hook 'erlang-mode-hook
     (lambda ()
         (setq inferior-erlang-machine-options '("-smp" "enable"))))
```

Comment: I discovered with your example that the inferior-erlang-machine-options is redefined in .emacs !

Comment: (setq inferior-erlang-machine-options '("-sname" "emacs" "-smp" "enable"))

Comment: looks like it's correct, but don't forget to reverse your edits to `erlang.el`

Comment: I don't have anymore the error BUT the program doesn't display a window

Comment: sorry, i can't help you with that. please make sure you have installed all required libraries. try `wx:demo()`...

Comment: You suggest wx:module_name() instead of module:start().

Comment: I think I have all required libraries because with "werl -smp" the program runs !

Comment: i suggested to try running `wx:demo().`, because it's defined in the wx module. i don't have any experience with wxerlang on windows, sorry.